# How can I include the development branch of Ansible with my playbooks when checked out via Git?

Tags: git, ansible, git-submodules

I've been developing several Ansible playbooks and require that they're run with a development version of Ansible. On my laptop that's not an issue, but I'm now attempting to setup a CI task in Bamboo that will consume the Playbooks as well any time changes are committed to our Git repo.

My thought was to create a Git submodule within our repository to a specific version of Ansible, and that way I can do a `git add submodule <ansible git repo>` and then `git clone --recursive` to pull down the official Ansible builds as part of my Playbook's repository on the CI worker nodes.

- Is this a good way to approach this?
- Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something similar using [ansible-galaxy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html)
You should create a file with all ansible components declared inside. Then all components will be downloaded using git. This approach could look like the following  `requirements.yml` example
:

```
 # ansible roles
 - src: https://gitlab.corp/teamname/ansible-roles
   path: roles/

 # ansible playbooks
 - src: https://gitlab.corp/teamname/ansible-playbooks
   path: playbooks/

 # ansible source
 - src: https://github.com/ansible/ansible
   version: devel
   path: ansible/
```

This will allow your to execute `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml`
 in order to fetch all your ansible environment components, including roles, playbooks and even the source of the ansible version you want. In this way, you will have all your ensible environment defined under one unique file.

Comment: This is an intriguing idea but it would be a bit of a catch 22 since I'd have to have Ansible installed to download using ansible-galaxy.